# reading char in loop

Tags: java, loops, char, system.in

I want to read char variable `a` in a loop, and increment variable `k` by one in each step of loop.

here is code in java:

```
public class Hello {
  public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException {
    int k, i;
    char a;
    k=0;
    for (i=0; i<=3; i++) {
      k++;
      a=(char) System.in.read();
      System.out.println(k);
    }
  }
}
```

here is result:

```
A  //variable a
1
2
3
B  //variable a
4
```

i need this result:

```
a  //variable a
1
c  //variable a
2
b  //variable a
3
y  //variable a
4
```

maybe i need some other method to read CHAR in loop ( not **SYSTEM.IN.READ()** ), but i am new in java.

Comment: No clear what you're asking, you don't want to use `System.int.read()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Scanner` class, which consumes input more predictably:

```
public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException {
    int k, i;
    char a;
    k = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        k++;
        a = in.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

The `next()` method returns a string, consisting of all the characters typed by the user, until they press the  key. So, by typing one character at a time (or by typing the desired character first), the string returned by `next()` will start with that character, so calling `charAt(0)` will retrieve it.

Note that there is no reason to run the loop for the first 4 times (0, 1, 2 and 3). You could replace the `for` statement with a `while (true)` statement.

Comment: why is there `.charAt(0)` ?

Comment: Check the amended answer. Thanks for selecting it. You can also upvote it, as well as upvote as many of the other answers as you find useful.  :-)

Comment: No problem. I upvoted the other answers, as well as yours, to give you a bit of help in building the reputation. Keep up the good work! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the `System.in.read` method - but without pressing `enter` after you introduce the first character:
I think the above answers solve your problem. However, I would like to explain you why this happens: you probably write `A` and press `enter`. The program reads `A` and `enter` - which is 2 chars: `\r\n` - therefore, the for loop sees at the first iteration `A`, at the second \r and at the third \n....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main (String args[]) {
  int k = 0;
  String a;
  while(true){
      a = keyboard.nextLine();
      k++;
      System.out.println(k);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
        int charCount = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(sc.hasNext() && charCount++<=3)
        {
            System.out.println(sc.next());
        }

      }
```